# angular: Why won't ng-repeat update with data from ajax call?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

From a controller a do a ajax call. The call can be triggered from two different links, both in the same html template. When using the above link that switches to the tab the data returned by the ajax call is displayed correctly. When using the `refresh` link the element in the ng-repeat won't be updated. Anyone knows why this is?

angularjs:

```
app.controller("ActiveSimulations",
    ["$scope", "$http", "socket",
    function($scope, $http, socket){

        $scope.active_simulations_dict = {};
        $scope.get_active_simulations = function() {
            var responsePromise = $http.get("/active_simulations");
            responsePromise.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.active_simulations_dict = data;

                console.log($scope.active_simulations_dict)
            });
            responsePromise.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('Warning - "AJAX failed!"')
                alert("AJAX failed!");
            });
        };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div id="followSim" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Follow running simulations</h3>
  <div class="inline-containers">
    <div id="simulation-list-wrapper">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in active_simulations_dict">
          <a ng-show="value[0] && value[2]" ng-click="followActiveSimulation(key)">
            {[{ value[0] }]} ( {[{ value[2] }]} is director)
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!--end simulation list wrapper-->

    <div id="refresh-simulation-list" ng-controller="ActiveSimulations">
        <a id="refresh-link"
           class="right-side"
            ng-click="get_active_simulations()">
          <i class="icon-refresh right-side"></i>
          refresh list
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: First idea: it's a separate controller, you are most likely breaking scope. So your active_simulations_dict at the repeat is a different variable than the one you access in your ActiveSimulations controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kasoban pointed out you might have an issue with multiple instances. Best practice is to create a *service* which handles your requests. You can inject it and call the request function from any controller then e.g.:

```
$scope.active_simulations_dict = RequestService.get_active_simulations();
```